# Algorithm with maximum flow in one-way directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Thank you for attention. I have a problem with the following task.

There are n vertices and we have (n * (n-1)) / 2 connections between vertices,  i.e. if we have a graph of 3 vertices, they are connected: **1-> 2** **1-> 3** **2-> 3**. If 4 vertices are connected: **1 -> 2** **1-> 3** **1-> 4** **2-> 3** **2-> 4** **3-> 4.**

*P* is the number of places in the train, *n* are the number of cities we have to visit.

We also have data on the number of passengers (*Wi*) who are willing to travel and the price of the ticket (*Vi*).

I need to find a way to get the highest amount for tickets sold.

**Example**

- Input: `P = 40 n = 3 W1 = 20 v1 = 2 W2 = 50 v2 = 3 W3 = 30 v3 = 3`
- Output: `160 (20x2, 10x3, 30x3)`.

Only maximum flow must be corrected because there are many solutions of paths. I was thinking of the *Edmond Carp algorithm*.

Can you present some ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some code to show what you have achieved so far? For example, how did you arrive at 160 for your example inputs? It's a lot easier for us to make suggestions (meaning you're likely to get more responses) when there's something concrete to work from, rather than creating something from scratch.

Comment: Unfortunately, but for now I do not have any idea to solve this task. I just analyzed Edmund Carp's algorithm but it's not a good direction. I am not counting on getting ready for a solution, but for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I think about algorithm Busackera-Gowena. Can this be a good choice?